# How to store firestore's new Timestamp object type in android's local database Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I'm storing date in Firestore using new object type recently introduced in Firestore which is in [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). I want to store these same Timestamp object in my SQLite powered [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

As far as I know currently Room does not support Timestamp. But it supports TypeConverter.

Are there any TypeConverter available to convert Timestamp. My concern is to avoid having two different Date conversions for Firestore and Room in my code. But as the limitation exists, I wouldn't mind using a TypeConverter to convert back and forth when storing in Room. This way I can still use Timestamp in code level.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) objects contain just two integer values - seconds since the unix epoch, and fractions of seconds (measured in nanoseconds) added to that.  If you don't need to extreme precision of nanoseconds, you can just store the seconds since epoch value and assume the fractional part is 0.

If you do need both values, then you'll need to map them to two different columns in sqlite.

As far as I know, there is no existing piece of software to do this for you, but it should be trivial to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

a `TypeConverter` won't be able to map two columns (it could only convert to `String` or `Date` representation); one could use the below class `TimeStamp`, together with the `@Embedded` annotation within another `@Entity`. while I merely wonder, if one has to declare the `tableName` for that class.

```
// @Entity(tableName = "tableName")
class TimeStamp {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "seconds")
    private long seconds = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "nanoseconds")
    private Integer nanoseconds = 0;       

    public Timestamp() {}

    @Ignore
    public Timestamp(long s, @Nullable Integer ns) {
        this.setSeconds(s);
        this.setNanoSeconds(ns);
    }

    public void setSeconds(long s) {
        if(s < 0) {s = 0;}
        this.seconds = s;
    }

    public void setNanoSeconds(@Nullable Integer ns) {
        if(ns == null || ns < 0) {ns = 0;}
        this.nanoseconds = ns;
    }

    public long getSeconds() {
        return this.seconds;
    }

    public long getMilliSeconds() {
        return (this.seconds * 1000);
    }

    public int getNanoSeconds() {
        return (int) this.nanoseconds;
    }

    public Date toDate() {
        return new Date(this.getMilliSeconds());
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.seconds) + "." + String.valueOf(this.nanoseconds);
    }
}
```